# Flex 4 addPopUp throwing error: "ArgumentError: Undefined state 'inactive' "

Tags: apache-flex, popup

I am trying to do something seemingly simple. Open a pop-up. Anyone else get this error?

```
 var myTitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
        myTitleWindow.title = "My Window Title";
        myTitleWindow.width = 220;
        myTitleWindow.height = 150;
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(myTitleWindow, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, true);
```

> ArgumentError: Undefined state 'inactive'.
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/getState()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/findCommonBaseState()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/commitCurrentState()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/commitProperties()
>       at spark.components.supportClasses::GroupBase/commitProperties()
>       at spark.components::Group/commitProperties()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()
>       at mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/addPopUp()
>       at mx.managers::PopUpManager$/addPopUp()

Comment: Do you have a custom skin for the title window declared in css?

Comment: Are you using Spark or MX components?  Is this a runtime error?

Comment: TitleWindow does not but Panel has a titleBackgroundSkin

Comment: Yes, runtime error and I am using Flex4 Spark components. The class resides in a module if that changes anything.

Comment: It errors when mx.managers.PopUpManagerImpl addPopUp() calls mx.managers.SystemManager getImplementation() method.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like my TitleWindow has its skin property set to spark.skins.spark.SkinnableContainerSkin. Shouldn't this be the default spark.skins.spark.TitleWindowSkin? I did a search for TitleWindow (as, mxml, css) and didn't see anything that might override the default skin. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the top-level Application as the "parent" argument for a popup of a class (TitleWindow) that the top-level Application hasn't imported when creating the pop-up within a module. I am just going to use the module but if you REALLY need the application to be the parent, here is the super-lame work-around: Just add an instance of TitleWindow to the main application.

```
private var oneVeryLameWorkAroundForParentingPopup:TitleWindow;
```

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/713069